# Do the methods in the services also have to be async when the controller is already using async in ASP .NET core?

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, asp.net-core, asynchronous

I am very new with **asynchronous programming** in ASP .NET CORE. I have made a **service** and **controller** for my checktoken functionality. This is my method in my **Authservice**:

```
public AppUser CheckToken(string token)
{
    if (token == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
        throw new CustomUnauthorizedException("Unauthorized", "You are not authorized to perform this action");

    var user = _context.DbSet<AppUser>().Query.FirstOrDefault(x => x.TOKEN == token);
    if (user == null)
        throw new CustomUnauthorizedException("Unauthorized", "You are not authorized to perform this action");

    return user;
}
```

And this is my method in the **controller**:

```
[HttpGet("{Id}")]
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Follow>>> GetFollows([FromHeader]string token, long Id)
{
    var user = _authService.CheckToken(token);
    return await _context.DbSet<Follow>().Query.Where(x => x.Id == Id && x.UserId == 
    user.UserId).ToListAsync();
}
```

My code is working good but a colleague has advised me this:

**Everything you do with a database you have to use async and Task**

He advised me to write the **service** method also in **async**

I use **depency injection** to call the method from the service in an async method.

My questions:

**Do I need to write the methods in the service also in async task?**

**Is this the right way to use asynchronous programming?**

Sources I have used:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/

Comment: That depends, if you want to process the objects which you get inside your services, to write them for example in a redis cache, the action which does this would be async. If you just load / save things with your service without storing them somewhere else it is not needed. I for myself, like to validate my objects so my services methods are mostly async.

Comment: So it's not a problem when I use async twices? One for the service and one for the controller?

Comment: nope that's fine, but if you really want to know, also performance based you will have to benchmark this problem

Comment: A lot of people get confused early on with `async`/`await`. All that `async` does, effectively, is let you write `await` inside that method. All the `await` does is *wait for something asynchronous that has already been started elsewhere*, without blocking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a general rule, any I/O code should be done asynchronously in an ASP.NET Core application. This includes all database queries.

Asynchronous code on ASP.NET actually makes each request run slightly *slower*, but it also reduces the number of threads used by your application, which allows it to handle many more simultaneous requests.